# Laravel many to many tables

Tags: laravel, model

I Have 4 tables:

```
members: id, lastname
license_member:id,license_id,member_id,valid_from
lesson_license_member: id,lesson_id,notes,license_member_id
lessons: id, number, date_time,instructor_id
```

In the models:

Member.php

```php
public function licenses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(License::class)->withPivot('valid_from','id');
}
```

LicenseMember:

```php
public function lessons(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Lesson::class,'lesson_license_member','license_member_id','lesson_id')->withPivot('notes');
    }
```

Lesson:

```php
 public function LicenseMember(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(LicenseMember::class,'lesson_license_member','license_member_id','lesson_id')->withPivot('notes');
    }
```

The MemberController:

```php
public function show($id)
    {
        $member = Member::find($id);
        return view('admin.members.members_detail',compact('member','id'));
    }
```

Now in my view I want to show, for the selected member, for every license he has, the lessons he made (date_time, number and instructor_id)

How can I do this?

Comment: You are missing the relation between license and lessons. A license has many lessons I guess but a lesson can only belong to a single license or to many licenses?

Comment: a member can have 1 or more licenses, a license belongs to 1 or more members. license_member and lessons are a many to many and the pivot table is lesson_license_member. I have also the table licenses but I don't need it now

Comment: I would expect to see a license table also, something that the foreign key license_id refers to.

Comment: Yes I have a table LIcense, witch is related with license_member, 1 to n, a license has many license_member